# Close all forms in a control in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I added a couple of forms to a panel. The forms have the properties

```
form.TopLevel = false;
form.Parent = pnlMain;
```

Now I want to iterate through all forms in pnlMain and close all forms. To do that I have the following code:

```
private void CloseForms()
{
    foreach(Form form in pnlMain.Controls.OfType<Form>())
        form.Close();
}
```

My problem is, that not all forms are closed.

In an example with four open forms: I counted the open forms,

```
int count = pnlMain.Controls.OfType<Form>().Count();
```

When I call CloseForms, only two forms are closed. The other two are closed on another call at CloseForms.

How can I close all forms with only one call?

Comment: Something in the oncloseing? or onclose events?

Comment: OT: You shouldn't have Forms in Panels. Take a look at UserControls.

Comment: I want forms as childs in this panel. So userconrols are not fitting.

Comment: Iterate it backwards with for()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't modify the collection while iterating on it. Try this

```
foreach(Form form in pnlMain.Controls.OfType<Form>().ToArray())
```

Comment: Although ToArray might be slightly more efficient, I would still use ToList as general practice.

Comment: This works. Thank you. 
But why is the collection modified if i don't use the .ToArray? Just for my knowledge :)

Comment: @Tomtom closing the form removes it from the container which is `pnlMain.Controls` in your case.